# ADLA U-SQL throwing error :The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (268435456) has been exceeded

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have been submitting a U-SQL job from last 2 months, I started receiving below exception today.

Job : Look through 20 files and loads into a physical table.

The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (268435456) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Error Message :

System error :See your account's health and contact support.

E_SMS_SYSTEM_FAILURE: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (268435456) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element. 
Line -1

Component : SMS

Message : 
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (268435456) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Resolution :
Please correct the user operation or contact support if the service outage persists.

Description : 
An exception has been raised from the metadata service client. This could be the result of a user operation or the SMS service being temporarily unavailable.

Details :N/A

Comment: This does not look like a U-SQL error. Can you paste the full error message please?

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue resolved when I remove insert into audit table script. Looks like there is limit on table fragmentation before its rebuild.